# ArcGIS Pro: Zonal statistics as table runs sucessfully but generates a blank table

Tags: arcgis-pro, zonal-statistics, euclidean

I am trying to find the average distance between locations in a relocated town. I am using the site addresses as the common feature between the tables as those stayed the same. I run the euclidean distance tool based on one town and now I am trying to run the zonal statistics as table tool but it keeps generating a blank table.
[image: screenshot showing my inputs and the generated blank table]

I have tried:

1. running the tool using the other town as a base
2. restarting my computer and the program
3. creating a new map document with only the necessary data to complete this part

Comment: Datasets the same coordinate systems?

Comment: Yes both the raster and town data are in NAD 1983 Contiguous USA Albers